# Find highest key value pairs from dictionaries inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to get the keys with the highest values out of a list. How would I go about getting that? BTW I'm new to programming and python in general, so this is mostly an exercise for myself.

Below is an example of basic info in dictionaries inside a list that I'd like to be able to get the values with the highest keys. In this case it would return 'Vinnie M' and 'Zoey M.'

Maybe there is a better way at structuring this data, but I'd like to have more info in the dictionaries, such as user IDs, time bid placed, etc. Also I need to be able to add new users without changing code, which is handled in another function, so don't worry about advice on adding a new user, unless my initial approach is flawed.

```
userList = [
    {'Full Name' : 'Ryan R.', 'Bid Amount' : 4.30},
    {'Full Name' : 'Zoey M.', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20},
    {'Full Name' : 'Max D.', 'Bid Amount' : 3.90},
    {'Full Name' : 'Vinnie M', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` for this purpose..

```
import operator
dict =  [
{'Full Name' : 'Ryan R.', 'Bid Amount' : 4.30},
{'Full Name' : 'Zoey M.', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20},
{'Full Name' : 'Max D.', 'Bid Amount' : 3.90},
{'Full Name' : 'Vinnie M', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20}
]`

max(dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Comment: your `dict` isn't a `dict`. Also please don't shadow the builtin `dict`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> userList = [
...     {'Full Name' : 'Ryan R.', 'Bid Amount' : 4.30},
...     {'Full Name' : 'Zoey M.', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20},
...     {'Full Name' : 'Max D.', 'Bid Amount' : 3.90},
...     {'Full Name' : 'Vinnie M', 'Bid Amount' : 5.20}
...     ]
>>> D = {i['Full Name']: i['Bid Amount'] for i in userList}
>>> mx = max(D.values())
>>> [i for i in D if D[i] == mx]
['Vinnie M', 'Zoey M.']
```

You can also do it without the intermediate `dict`. But seems an unnatural data structure unless you can have duplicate Full Names

```
>>> mx = max(i['Bid Amount'] for i in userList)
>>> [i['Full Name'] for i in userList if i['Bid Amount'] == mx]
['Zoey M.', 'Vinnie M']
```

Comment: Hmm.. couldn't get it to work. Maybe I'm writing it wrong. I was able to to get the max value of 5.2, but not the [i for i in D if D[i] == mx]. How would i write that into a function?