# How to code for the value of "month" which produced the highest profit in a year?

Tags: python, list

Out of all the months in the year, I need to code the month with largest total balance (it's June as all together June has the biggest "amount" value)

```py
lst = [
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 300, 'day': 3, 'month': 'June'},
    {'account': 'y\\*', 'amount': 550, 'day': 9, 'month': 'May'},
    {'account': 'z\\*', 'amount': -200, 'day': 21, 'month': 'June'},
    {'account': 'g', 'amount': 80, 'day': 10, 'month': 'May'},
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 30, 'day': 16, 'month': 'August'},
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 100, 'day': 5, 'month': 'June'},
]
```

The problem is that both "amount" and the name of the months are values.

I tried to find the total for each month, but I need to use for loop to code the highest month "amount".

My attempt:

```py
get_sum  = lambda my_dict, month: sum(d['amount']
for d in my_list if d['month'] == month)
total_June = get_sum(my_list,'June')
total_August = get_sum(my_list),'August')
```

Comment: Dictionaries in Python cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: It is a list (labeled dictionary) In this case what would I do?

Comment: Then please fix your example in your question. `list = { ... }`, the `list` variable is still a dictionary.

Comment: Please fix the original sample dictionary. It should be a list, and every sequence account, amount, day, month should a dictionary within the list.

Then please make it more explicit as to what is it you want as output.

You just want highest month, value: June, 100?

Comment: The rows are missing the `{` and `}` characters that would make it actually be a list of dicts. Maybe these will help? [dict](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/literals.html) [list](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/literals.html)

Comment: In that case, it looks to me like this question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210153/find-highest-key-value-pairs-from-dictionaries-inside-list

Comment: @dskrypa in the program I do have the {} but it does not work, could you please provide possible suggestions?

Comment: @ferreiradev thank you that link however, I tried to implement that code and the output was basicly the list in a string

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 300, 'day': 3, 'month': 'June'},
    {'account': 'y\\*', 'amount': 550, 'day': 9, 'month': 'May'},
    {'account': 'z\\*', 'amount': -200, 'day': 21, 'month': 'June'},
    {'account': 'g', 'amount': 80, 'day': 10, 'month': 'May'},
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 30, 'day': 16, 'month': 'August'},
    {'account': 'x\\*', 'amount': 100, 'day': 5, 'month': 'June'},
]

# convert list of dictionaries to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# Get the row / series that has max amount. 
# idxmax returns an index for loc.
max_series_by_amount = df.loc[df['amount'].idxmax(axis="index")]

# Get only month and amount in a plain list
print(max_series_by_amount[["month", "amount"]].tolist())
['May', 550]
```

*Please note that using pandas adds a substantial amount of dependencies to the project, that said, pandas is commonly imported anyway for data science or data manipulation tasks. Pierre D solutions here are definitively faster.*

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (among many):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mo_total = {
    k: sum([d.get('amount', 0) for d in v])
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter('month')), key=itemgetter('month'))
}
>>> mo_total
{'August': 30, 'June': 200, 'May': 630}

>>> max(mo_total.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
('May', 630)
```

Without `itemgetter`:

```py
bymonth = lambda d: d.get('month')
mo_total = {
    k: sum([d.get('amount', 0) for d in v])
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=bymonth), key=bymonth)
}
```

Yet another way, using `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

tot = defaultdict(int)

for d in lst:
    tot[d['month']] += d.get('amount', 0)
>>> tot
defaultdict(int, {'June': 200, 'May': 630, 'August': 30})

>>> max(tot, key=lambda k: tot[k])
'May'
```

Comment: Thank you for the repose. I tried this and I get
" ImportError: cannot import name 'itemegetter' from 'operator') "

Comment: wow, `itemgetter` was already present as of Python 3.5. How old exactly is the Python version you are using?

Comment: That it surprising it is Python 3.9. Unusual that it does not work

Comment: Accuracy is extremely important in programming.  Typos will result in problems.  `itemegetter` is not the same as `itemgetter`.